Vertical centering in TextView broke in API35
My TextView is being created inside an activity like this:
    final int SIZE = 55, TEXT_SIZE = 40;

    float d = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density,
        sd = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (SIZE * sd), (int) (SIZE * sd));
    llp.setMargins((int) (2 * d), (int) (2 * d), (int) (2 * d), (int) (2 * d));
    llp.gravity = 0x31;
    tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tv.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    tv.setText(s); // The text doesn't matter

    tv.setTextLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
    tv.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);

I'm looking at the app side by side in Android 14 emulator (API34) and in Android 15 one, same hardware skin (Pixel 2). On the former, the text is centered vertically, on the latter it's shifted down. The font looks identical, but I can't check the internals (e. g. the internal padding). Looks like as if there was some change to the text layout logic that I'm missing. The app is targeting API34.
Here is API34 (blue background added during debugging, to see the view boundaries):

And this is API35:

The text is clearly shifted down, while the glyph looks otherwise identical. I'm aiming for vertical centering (or at least consistency). Is there a new layout parameter in API35 that I'm missing?
The text is in Japanese (on an otherwise English locale device). This might be relevant.
